# perl multiple regex match over multiple lines

Tags: regex, perl, multilinestring

I'm struggling with trying to capture multiple matches within  a group of lines in a text file.

The data takes on a bunch of forms like

> AO22_X1N_A9PP96CTS_C24 SYN_INC_187 ( .A0 ( test_so6 ) , .A1 ( n2218 )
>   , 
>       .B0 ( U_PAUSEdata_ff_int_28_ ) , .B1 ( n2 ) , .Y ( n2597 ) ) ;
>
> NAND3_X1R_A9PP96CTUL_C16 SYN_INC_154 ( .A ( n1563 ) , 
>       .B ( U_PAUSEwcnt ) , .C ( n1640 ) , .Y ( n1467 ) ) ;

The first piece is a name. Might want tat later but for now I am interested in the ports ex  .A ( net )
Ideally I want to capture all the input net  names (those with A,B,C,D etc)  and the single output .Y ( net)

Eventually I want to store them into a hash where the output net is the key and the data is a ref to the array of inputs but for now I'm just trying to get all the input nets to be captured.

This is what I'm currently working with

```
open (FILE, "<maca") or die("Can not open $file");
  while (defined(my $cur_line = <FILE>)) {

    if ($cur_line =~ m/[A-Z].*?\.[A-C]\d* \( (.*?) \).*?;/mg) { 
      print "THIS gate $cur_line $1 $2 $3\n";  
      }
  }
```

I'm trying for this display

> THIS gate     NAND3_X1R_A9PP96CTUL_C16 SYN_INC_154 ( .A ( n1563 ) , 
>       .B ( U_PAUSEwcnt ) , .C ( n1640 ) , .Y ( n1467 ) ) ;
>
> n1563 U_PAUSEwcnt n1640

But I get this.  Actually I don't care about the first line just the 2nd. The first is for debugging.  I thought the m would search multiple lines and the g would globally match the multi line string.  What am I missing

> THIS gate     .B ( U_PAUSEwcnt ) , .C ( n1640 ) , .Y ( n1467 ) ) ;
>
> n1640

Comment: If `$cur_line` is a single line, you should not use mulitline regexp. Try instead to match the three fields in a single regexp without the `g` and `m` modifier

Comment: Use a Verilog parser: https://metacpan.org/pod/Verilog-Perl

Comment: @Håkon Hægland   it is actually multiple lines in a file.  The multi line data is terminated by  ;

Comment: @toolic   I had no idea that there was a verilog parser. Thanks for pointing that out.   I'll see if the synthesized netlist can be pulled in.  I might use that or just steal the code from the module.  Just want a simple test script. No need to pull the whole design into memory

Comment: The `vhier` helper script might be a good place to start.

Comment: @togaclad So to clarify the format: `$cur_line` is equal to 5 lines in your example, or is it equal to the top two lines (since there is a `;` after the second line)?

Comment: @toolic.  There is lots of good examples in those modules. The one thing that it does not do, and I really needed, was elaboration.  Basically that is what I am after but with the example from the those modules and the great comments from everyone I think I have enough to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're looking for something like this:

```
while ($data =~ /(\w+)\s*\((.+?)\)\s*;/gm) {
  my $line = $1;
  my $vals = $2;
  while ($vals =~ /\.(\w+)\s*\(\s*(\w+)\s*\)/g) {
    print "$line .. $1: $2.\n"
  }
}
```

I called the variable `$data` as it has all lines - correct?
I first split the lines, capturing the string between the `( .. )` , then pull out the key - value pairs. Looks like all names are alpha-numeric + "_" which is nicely captured per `\w`.

Hope this helps?

Comment: Oh I see it now. I was using a while to read in  my $cur_line = <FILE>   and then using the same  $cur_line to regex as i detailed.  I did not realize I needed to pull the global multi string match into a variable and then use a while to walk through it.

Comment: Ah I see - it would have been easier if you posted your full code ;)
no problem, you can continue doing that (is a good idea). above code will also work if you use it with individual lines. (of course then you can use `if` and kick out the `gm` )

Comment: hmmm no still fighting with it. Seemed to be working at first but is not matching past the first line.

Comment: Wait it works.  Okay I had to use the gms modifier on  the first while.          
`my $data = read_file("maca");
while ($data =~ m/([A-Z]\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+\((.+?)\)\s*;/mgs) {
  my $port_net_pairs = $3;
  while ($port_net_pairs =~ m/\.(\w+)\s+\(\s+(\w+)\s+\)/g) {
    my $port = $1;
    my $net = $2;
    print "      $port : $net\n";
  }
}`   Now the only challenge I see is some ports are not just word chars but have square brackets.  ex     .B ( TX_cnt[0] )

Comment: woohoo solved that with 
`while ($port_net_pairs =~ m/\.(\w+)\s+\(\s+([\w|\[|\]]+)\s+\)/g) {`

Comment: great! in fact you don't even need the `|` in the pattern `[\w|\[|\]]+` so you can use `[\w\[\]]+` . if this answered the question please hit accept, thanks!